# Verify that a method of a regular (non-mock) object was called via reflection

Tags: java, testing, reflection, junit, mockito

I have code that looks like this:

```
abstract class Parent {
   public void dispatch(...) { ... }
}
```

The job of the `dispatch` method is to determine which method of the subclass should be called based on the value of the parameters, and then call it; this is done via runtime annotation analysis. So, if I have a subclass that looks like this:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    @CallThisMethodIfA
    public Thing aMethod(...) { ... }

    @CallThisMethodIfB
    public Thing bMethod(...) { ... }
}
```

then calling `child.dispatch(A)` should invoke `aMethod` (where `child` is an instance of `Child`). Of course, I'm simplifying as much as possible here - these aren't the actual annotations and args that I have.

My question is how to test this behavior. I tried something like:

```
Child child = new Child(...);
child.dispatch(A);
verify(child, times(1)).aMethod(...)
```

which gave me a `NotAMockException` because, of course, `child` is not a mock but a real object. I'm not 100% certain on how spying works, but I also tried instantiating `Child` using `@Spy`, and while that didn't throw an exception it also didn't register a call to `aMethod` because, I'm guessing, spying doesn't actually imitate the internal behavior of the class. How would I go about doing this? I guess I could manually initialize `Child` and make `aMethod` return a very specific instance of `Thing` that I can then check, but that doesn't feel clean to me (what if some other method just so happens to return an equal instance?)

Comment: To test `Parent`, implement a `class FakeChild` with those two methods, with some kind of state to keep track of each time they are called. To test `Child`, just test that `aMethod` and `bMethod` return the right things.